# django admin using formset

Tags: django, django-admin

Models.py:

```
class ExperienceSynopsis(Audit):
    user                    = models.ForeignKey(User, null = True, blank = True)
    area_skill              = models.CharField(max_length = 50, help_text = 'Example: Testing,Development,etc..')
    experience              = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.area_skill
```

Forms.py:

```
class ExperienceSynopsisForm(forms.Form):
    area_skill           = fields.CharField(max_length=50, help_text = 'Example: Testing,Development,etc..')
    experience           = fields.CharField(max_length=50)
ExperienceFormset = formsets.formset_factory(ExperienceSynopsisForm, formset = RequiredFormSet, extra = 0)
```

I want to add formset in admin.py. How to enable admin for this model.Please help me.

Comment: It's easier to customize formset for `InlineModelAdmin`. Can you use inline then?

Answer (score 7):

The Django docs and tutorial give a headstart how this works

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.StackedInline

Add your Formset to your Inline object and you're set up

```
class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    formset = # Yours

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        BookInline,
    ]
```

Use `save_formset` to override saving if needed

Comment: Hmm is there no way to use a formset in admin without it being an inline? Like a form for adding multiple books at once? I know you can do this in your view via formset. I couldn't find a good solution for admin yet. Is there one?